# Saving lists as a csv in python

Tags: python, list, csv

This is my current CSV file:

```
BookId,BookTitle,Author ,Price(£),Subject,NoofCopies
1,Sherlock Holmes, Arthur Conan Doyle, 10.00, Crime, 3
2,The Computing Book, Robert, 2.00, Computing, 9
3,Another Book,Steeve, 4.50, Action, 1
```

If I use this code to read in the csv file:

```
def readbookcsv():
    database = []
    filename = "csvbooks.csv"
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                    database.append(row)
    return database
```

I get a list full of other lists that I use in the rest of my code to add or change data within these lists:

```
"['BookId', 'BookTitle', 'Author ', 'Price(£)', 'Subject', 'NoofCopies']","['1', 'Sherlock Holmes', ' Arthur Conan Doyle', ' 10.00', ' Crime', ' 3']","['2', 'The Computing Book', ' Robert', ' 2.00', ' Computing', ' 9']","['3', 'Another Book', 'Steeve', ' 4.50', ' Action', ' 1']"
```

Yet when attempting to overwrite the save file I always end up clearing the file entirely, appending the above list to a single cell or overwriting the csv with only the list, is there a way of changing this list back into the same format the csv file is in and then saving it?

Saving:

```
 with open('csvbooks.csv', 'wt') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    wtr.writerow(booklist)

with open('csvbooks.csv', 'at') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerow(booklist)
```

Comment: Where is the `save` method?

Comment: Please show your attempts that do not work.

Comment: Whoops added now, I didnt include originally because it doesnt work at all and its been changed many times from when i started. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot feed the whole list to the `writerow()` method.
Use the `writerows()` method to write the whole list
at once:

```
with open('csvbooks_out.csv', 'wt') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    wtr.writerows(booklist)
```

Alternatively, you can write row-by-row:

```
with open('csvbooks_out.csv', 'wt') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    for row in booklist:
        wtr.writerow(row)
```

Now `csvbooks_out.csv` has the same format as your input file.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! The only problem is this code seems to add an additional blank row when it saves that then gets read in, and if saved again even more blank rows are added. Is there a way either in reading in or saving to get rid of these extra blank rows?

Comment: I don't see any blank rows. Check your `booklist`  if it has  an empty list in it somewhere. Maybe at the end.

Comment: Ok I will test the program now and update the main post so I can format it better :) Thanks a lot <3

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Ok well I did some testing but I cant edit my main post because it says i havent tagged the code as code even though I have :/ It seems when I save the rows it is adding in blank ones, that then get read in as a blank list between other lists.

Comment: Check your original input file for blank lines and remove them. Also the last empty line, if any.

Comment: The original input file has no blank lines, yet the output file has 2 at the end and one between each line, if there is anything i can do to get more data please ask :)

Comment: If you are on Windows you need to open the input file with `rb` and the output with 'wb'. In Python 3 use `newline=''`.

Comment: This seems to lead to another error but I think I can fix that myself :) Thanks for your help man <3 EDIT: I don't think I can fix that myself haha

Answer (score 0):

To convert the list of lists(the actual rows) to the csv-Format you could use something like these functions:

```
def listToRow(list, separator = ','):
row = ''
for item in list:
    row += item + separator
row = row[:len(row)-1]
return row  

def listToString(list):
    str = ''
    for item in list:
        str += listToRow(item) + '\n'
    return str
```

The method listToRow takes the "row-list" as a parameter, concatenates the list items and adds a separator(the second parameter) between them. By default I just used the ',' like in you example.

The method listToString takes the list of lists as a parameter, concatenates them and adds line breaks('\n'), so you would have an extra line for every row.

Finally you can use the following function to append the string to the actual csv file.

```
def appendStringToCSV(csvName = 'csv.csv', string = ''):
    f = open(csvName, 'a')
    f.write(string)
    f.close()
```